# Issue detecting second monitor when using nvidia proprietary driver

Tags: drivers, display, nvidia-geforce

I recently changed my NVIDIA drivers on my ubuntu 22.04 machine from Nouveau to nvidia-driver-525-open, as I needed a proprietary driver to use CUDA. While installing, I was told that UEFI secure boot required additional configuration, so I was invited to set a password, for "Enroll MOK" and "Change Secure Boot state" to enter on reboot. On reboot I found the "Enroll MOK" part but not the other, I typed my password here to enroll key.

After this everything has booted fine, except my second monitor plugged in via displayport (in pc) to HDMI (in monitor) is no longer detected. I assume this is due to the change in graphics card but I was wondering if there was a resolution which doesn't require a reversion to the nouveau drivers, as these aren't compatible with CUDA.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What video card do you have?  The `nvidia-driver-5xx-open` will only work on specific NVIDIA cards.  Have you tried the non-open driver?

Comment: I have an RTX 2060, I was actually just going through the CUDA installation and I think it prompted me to change to the non-open, which now appears to be the one in use. Now both monitors are working. Is there a general way to find our which would be permissible for a given card?

Comment: All the cards supported for those drivers are listed at https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/196728/en-us/ under Supported Products

Comment: Thanks so much! :)